# Can an artificial intelligence serve as a judge and/or posek?

Tags: halacha-theory, technology, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

If the vast corpus of halachic material including information on how sources are weighed and how halacha has been decided through the ages was compiled and processed through an artificial intelligence algorithm such that when asked hear arguments from two parties in a court case and to render halachic decisions this AI would be technically capable of so doing. Would such a machine be allowed by Jewish law to operate as a judge in a non-capital case or generally to dispense rulings which would be considered binding in areas of halacha?

Comment: "*how halacha has been decided through the ages"* - no such thing, it is pretty much arbitrary - why Shu"A was chosen over Tur?

Comment: See what I answered there, AI can surely serve as an arbitrator!